# how can I create a really simple upload - download website

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am attempting to collect files from a number of friends from around the world. Later on I will also allow everyone to download from this shared repository.
Some key facts:

- Most of them have little knowledge for file transfer and even less motivation to "try". So they will stop caring to upload files if I tell them to install some ftp/webdav client and give them detailed info on how to send files.
- I have a high server to my disposal where I could setup a webserver that can do multiple file upload/download.
- the data size will be considerable so I can not use one of available free services (such as `dropbox` etc.)
- I have zero knowledge regarding webpage programming.

So I would like to create an extremely lightweight page (hopefully an html page is enough), where there is some introductory text, underneath I can see the files that exist in the current directory and finally have an "upload" button so as to allow people to upload files (multiple files!).

A possible page could be similar to this  http://taper.alienbase.nl/mirrors/. As you can see there exists some text and the current folder contents. There exists no upload capability however. Also If a folder is completely empty (no `index.html` etc) , `apache` decides automatically to create an 'ls table' of the current directory contect.

Is there any easy code that implements file upload? I read about `plupload` [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/upload-multiple-images-via-website) but it seems somewhat more complicated (it also requires `java`? - I didn't find any setup info)

I want to set it up on an `apache` webserver, in a linux box.

If you have a tutorial in mind that may give installation and setup information about how to set it up, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You'll want to start with some introductory tutorials using whatever technology you choose.  (PHP is indicated in your tags, so that's as good a place to start as any.)  Make some attempts to develop this functionality.  For each component of the functionality (identify a user, upload a file, store a file, display a page, download a file, etc.) make some attempt to develop it.  If you get stuck, identify the specifics of the problem you're facing and we'll be happy to help resolve that problem.  Currently this question is simply too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The link you gave us is mod for apache as it looks like. If you don't have knowledge of php, you should buy a file hosting script (try codecanyon) or search after one that is free (try github).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously used [this jQuery Upload File Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). Its simple to implement and has the option to drag and drop multiple files for upload.

Comment: hi there, this is promising  and simple. do you have any tutorial as to where to install the scripts and how to run it ?